# What is the clearest way to display "less than"?

Tags: accessibility, numbers, symbols

I'm currently working a sliding filter in a UI that presents a "distance to" option.

Which of the following would best in my situation?

1. < 2.1 miles
2. under 2.1 miles
3. 2.1 miles or less

Example:

[image]

Comment: I think one design factor to consider is how screen readers deal with these sorts of things.  JAWS reads < as 'less'.  I don't use a mac so I don't know what it does here.

Comment: Put a slidey circle handle on the other (left) side of the blue part of the slider too. Then you can make x < y < z queries too.

Comment: Is there a map view also where you could show an increasing/decreasing circle perhaps?

Comment: Item 3 does not mean the same thing as items 1 and 2.  Are you intending to represent "less than" or "less than or equal to"?

Comment: Unless you're really trying to re-design the wheel from scratch, why not Post three or four each examples of what, thus far, you see as best and worst common practice?

Comment: @viktorMellgren there is a Map View that corresponds with this but it does not have a radius drawn out. These distances are custom set and might not perfectly align to where the pin/marker might be on the map.

Comment: @theonlygusti we did some heat mapping and session recordings of an existing variant that does allow for both but it seemed to cause more confusion. It was previously labeled at the bottom with "Closest" and "Farthest", which found users just clicking the slider at the lower end (which we assumed they expected was a "sort by")

Comment: Frame challenge: Changing the label to "Maximum distance" would make the intent clearer.

Comment: I agree with the frame challenges: why say any form of "less than" at all? Why not simply give a rounded distance? It would be much more intuitive.

Comment: @theonlygusti - Scuilla mentioned that it's a search for a conference, ie. the starting location is fixed, so unless you want to support people searching with "I want to be close to the venue, but not _too_ close", it doesn't add much value to have the minimum be adjustable.

Comment: "Within 2.1 miles" is common.

Comment: @EricTowers, while "less than" is not technically the same as "less than or equal", there's no way to measure continuous values like distances in such a way that it would make a difference. If it was about something countable, it would be different.

Comment: Was there a preceding slider with the price? If so, you could use the same wording, e.g. "Up to $100", "Up to 2 miles." The user will then have been primed as to the meaning.

Comment: "within" is another choice: Distance to Venue **within** x miles — "within" is technically exclusive, but the word is fudgy enough that you don't have to care, if you say "within 10 miles" you can include exactly 10 miles.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

## If you want sex just say it

[If you want sex just say it](https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/75289/16924) - You should strive to convey information in the clearest way possible, when possible.

`< 2.1 miles` is < clear than `less than 2.1 miles`.

In the form `< 2.1 miles` people could infer `<` as "look left".

## < ≠ <=

Note that `less than 2.1 miles` is not the same as `2.1 miles or less` - the former is exclusive (2.1 miles) whilst the later is inclusive. Given the unit though, I don't think anyone will care so the shorter version wins.

## X . . . > . . X .

*But*, in `2.1 miles or less` the important quantity is front-loaded, whereas in `less than 2.1 miles` it is the third token.

## Max

You could equally use the caption `Max distance to venue`, which will leave you having not to think about this - just put `2.1`.

## DRY

**Don't Repeat Yourself** - There is already `miles` in the scale, so you can just use `2.1` instead of `2.1 miles`. Can you tell 60 what in this :

[image: A slider with a scale in celsius and a thumb with the label 60]

[source](https://material-ui.com/components/slider/#custom-marks)

## Thumbs

And as seen above, you can use a thumb; but that's not great if users need to see the value when not interacting with the slider (unless the thumb is always there).

## Conclusion

It all depends, but my vote is `Max distance to venue` with `2.1`

Comment: DRY is in contradiction with the advice to say what you mean. Also, it might be redundant for someone who can see the scale and the label simultaneously, but it would not be for someone using a screen reader.

Comment: "If you want sex just say it" also implies some conciseness (according to your own words). I guess it depends on the target audience, but for me "less than 5 milliseconds" is definitely *less* clear than "< 5 ms".

Comment: It took me a while to parse “is < clear than”. Same for “< ≠ <=”.

Comment: Your example with 60 is no good. First, the 60 appears inside a kind of arrow used on the maps, so it's not immediately obvious that this point is 60 °C, rather than e.g. "60 km from the point of temperature measurement" (yes, I'm exaggerating). Second, the scale already repeats "°C" in each tick, so 60 looks even more unrelated to the scale. In this example it should really be 60 °C, not simply 60.

Comment: @CarstenS It took me a while to parse that too, but that's because "<" isn't a word, so it fits weird in a sentence.  In the context of "< 2.1 miles", it's easy to parse.

Comment: @CarlKevinson, indeed, but it makes me not trust anything that is being said on that subject in this answer.

Comment: Yeah coming from a programming/math background, the less-than symbol is *much* easier for me to parse than the sentence form. So it very much depends on the target audience.

Comment: I disagree only on the DRY part - you want the screen reader to say "less than two point one miles", not just "less than two point one". Also, although it is technically redundant, I've seen actual user confusion over this kind of thing... they may not be looking at the units as stated under the slider, they're looking at the current value. There are other less-charitable reasons why some users won't "get it" without the otherwise redundant repetition of the units.

Comment: I think of "DRY" - Don't Repeat Yourself - as a much more of a programming concept  rather than a UX concept, and have understood it to mean that if you are repeating a task, write one function for the task and call that function rather than writing the same function again and again and again and....

Comment: @WPWPWP DRY does have its origin in programming and is normally seen as you have described. But concepts like "Single Source of Truth" are not unique to programming. There is also the "Multiple Representation Problem" and many other names to describe the same thing - whether it is process or state being duplicated, updates require more work hence higher maintenance and cost. The DRY you know is just a special case often applied in programming to a much more generic concept. Lastly, remember that redundancy is sometimes desired - like with DNA or CRC etc.

Answer (score 8):

The other answers seem to be missing the forest for the trees. The problem isn't visual, but semantic.

When creating key-value pairs, the least ambiguous solution tends to involve defining your left-hand keys such that you can keep the right-hand value side as elementary as possible (e.g., numeric scalars). In your case:

**Maximum distance to Venue**  2.1 miles

By redefining your "distance" key as a "maximum distance" key, you can avoid your presentation issues completely.

Comment: He's not the only one apparently missing a forest , but it's a great line of reasoning alright.

Answer (score 7):

You could place the minimum value on the left and increments throughout the rest of the bar:

[image: Increment slider bar]

The "distance" in the title implies that values "up to" the selected one will be included in the filter.

If the min/max and steps would logically change based on availability and you want to avoid displaying "sorry, no results", you could use checkboxes with user-friendly ranges and show the number of results next to each. (To answer your original question - the example below uses "Less than".)

[image: Distance From filter]

Comment: The min/max of this slider will be dynamic so the steps won't be easy to determine. It has the potential to range from 0 - 15, while also being 4.3 - 5.2 in some scenarios.

Comment: What is the scenario where the fine-tuned range would be used? Does the user to define  something extremely precise?

Comment: This is an app that shows hotels available for a specific conference. The filters change because of availability, not a user action. The min/max is determined by the distances for the closest and farthest hotel.

Comment: @Scuilla, is that to say that these 'filters' are actually a display feature, not a user input control?

Comment: @Dan - I interpret that to mean that the slider will adjust based on the data (how near/far the available options are), rather than having a pre-set min/max. So if there are no hotels closer than 2 miles, the minimum value of the slider will be 2, not 0.

Comment: that list of checkboxes doesn't seem to make sense. What would be the utility of checking, say the first and third, but not the middle when the latter choices include the former ones? Radio buttons would make more sense, unless of course you mean `[ ] less than 1/2 miles, [ ] from 1/2 to 1 miles, [ ] from 1 to 2 miles`.

Comment: @Dan - Beejamin is correct. The is no uniform initial min/max, this will be dynamic but the slider itself is very much a user controlled input. Sorry for the confusion!

Answer (score 5):

The slider in the position you illustrate controls a filter which will confine results to those with distance less than 2.1 miles. This is not the same as stating that the distance to one particular venue is less than 2.1 miles. Therefore, I suggest "up to 2.1 miles".

Answer (score 2):

I suggest 2. As user may not understand or overlook mathematical operators.

Comment: Hello Kevin, thanks for taking the time to respond to that. We are trying here to include links and examples. Opinions are great but most valuable is research, sources with other places where solution or parts of it exist. Maybe with a small update, the answer can be better.

Comment: @MikeMark A common principle in UX design is keeping it simple, and that's exactly what Kevin is doing. The only answerer here who uses a link, links to an earlier answer of their own, so I'm not sure how much that backs up their opinion.

Comment: UX Design is also about creating trust and confidence. An opinion not based on facts, research and data won't inspire confidence. Sometimes an opinion is enough but this site tries to not become a twitter survey but a place where we learn and base our answers more on data and less on opinions. People adding links to similar questions are not doing wrong if the questions are related. Adding any link wouldn't work.

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of good answers here, but one thing I haven't seen addressed is that you can add clarity by using the more specific set of descriptors for your type of value (distance in this case), rather than the generic ones that work for any type of value (min/max/less/more). These brings in extra information without needing extra words.

- *Inclusive/Generic*: `Maximum distance 2.1 miles`
- *Inclusive/Distance-specific*: `No further than 2.1 miles`
- *Exclusive/Generic*: `Less than 2.1 miles`
- *Exclusive/Distance-specific*: `Closer than 2.1 miles`

You can apply this to lots of things: Price (`Cheaper` instead of `Less`), Weight (`Heavier` instead of `More`), etc.

In your specific case, it might depend on how the search is working: `Closer` might imply that it is close to the user's location, rather than the origin of the search (which may be actually or conceptually the same, of course). If you want to guard against that, I might use `(Venues) within 2.1 miles`.

Comment: "further" refers to progress; "farther" to distance.

Comment: @Kaz - depends on which flavour of English you're writing. US English, definitely - I didn't realise that, thanks! [OED/British English](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/further#Usage_notes) (which I guess is where my Australian English derives) suggests they're mostly interchangeable, but _farther_ is comparative (a is farther than b) while _further_ is non-comparative (it's no further than 2km). I probably couldn't have told you that before I checked, but I definitely had a strong preference for 'further' when writing that!

Answer (score 1):

The UI issue here is that "< 2.1 miles" is contradicted by the slider, which is about halfway between right here and ten miles. It must be nonlinear.

Here is how we fix everything:

[image: proposed UI]

Firstly, give me the *exact* figure. Don't tell me it's a secret number less than 2.1 miles—especially if the only other clue you give me is a position on a nonlinear slider whose only labels are on the endpoints.

Secondly, if the slider has a nonlinear scale, learn from a 1970's audio slider knob and put in some ticks which indicate that.

I would also use round numbers for the slider endpoints: how about 0 miles and 10.0 (or just 10) miles.

Comment: "Firstly, give me the exact figure" - I think @Scuilla's example is giving the exact figure, just of the maximum value of the range. The "less than" refers to the whole range. Also, they mentioned that the max-value is dynamic based on data - ie. there's at least one data point at or just under 10.7 miles.