# Are there conventions to indicate a new item in a list?

Tags: lists

Let's say a user adds some products to a cart and we'd like to distinguish the items that were just added compared to the items that were already in the cart.

Or a user uploaded some files into something like Google Drive and we'd like to visually distinguish the new files.

For example, in forums, it's very common to put the title of the thread in bold to indicate a new or unread post in that thread.

Are there any other conventions or research done about this?

Comment: Are the items in one list or they are nested lists in a list?

Comment: Popular products that people use often have their own conventions, as you can see in the answers below. Frequent users will understand or get used to them. If there is a general agreed on convention, I wonder why you don't know it already or why it isn't mentioned in any of the answers. So it is safe to assume there isn't one that your users are guaranteed to understand. If you are looking for a way to advertise new items to people that aren't familiar with the application you will have to use more explicit, more descriptive methods like the `NEW ITEM` tag mentioned in one of the answers.

Comment: @jazZRo I agree. I was hoping there would be some research in this area. As it is I don't know if I can mark any answer as correct.

Comment: See also https://ux.stackexchange.com/q/75240/36618 and https://www.nngroup.com/articles/visual-indicators-differentiators/

Comment: Thanks @bishop ! Please put that Nielsen article in an answer and I will mark it as valid since this is the closest to my original question.

Comment: @Pier Done! https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/145854/36618

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As evidenced by the answers here, and in [other UX.SE questions](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/75240/how-to-indicate-that-an-element-is-new-in-a-list), there are many ways to go about it. This gives us a hint that there are no standards, conventions, or guidelines to follow -- though it doesn't preclude those forming in the future.

The absence of such standards is not surprising: a list can have many representative forms -- bulleted, with or without images and thumbnails, descriptions, attributes, and so on -- and has to adapt *its specific form* to a variety of different environments and needs.

Thus, the best we can do is turn to research on generic ways to differentiate items in a list. In 2016, [Nielson Norman Group](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/visual-indicators-differentiators/) measured that:

> Users are roughly 37% faster at finding items within a list on a web page when visual indicators vary both in color and icon compared to text alone. If choosing between using color or an icon, icons with strong information scent perform better than color alone.

From this research, we can take away that if the attribute of "newness" is the most important differentiator in your list, then use variations in *color and icon* to highlight the difference. Color alone *helps*, but does not perform as well as *both*.

You can see that the examples in other answers use this technique, suggesting that common implementations follow the research.

When faced with this problem, my recommendation would be to evaluate your list's specific form and introduce variation in color and icon to highlight the most important attribute. If there are many important attributes, provide a way to sort and filter.

Comment: It's a real pity that IE didn't make it. We would have a de facto standard then, like with Windows. OK, for just a few years at least. Until the next version...

Comment: And the obligatory https://xkcd.com/927/.

Answer (score 12):

No research but I'd prefer some sort of tag (e.g. <kbd>NEW ITEM</kbd> or <kbd>NEW IN CART</kbd> [Thx @wizzwizz4, for the hint!]) or clear text: *New item in cart*. I'm not sure whether bold text can be easily distinguished from normal one by visually impaired and on all conceivable devices.

And bold text can mean different things in different apps: selected for further action, highlighting a special offer, item with personal discount or, well, new item at this place... you name it.

Acoording to [*Visual Indicators to Differentiate Items in a List*](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/visual-indicators-differentiators/): "**Both** [icon and color] **Is Best**".

Comment: I'd prefer the more verbose wording "new item in cart" instead of just "new item". Someone might understand "new item" to mean a newly launched product instead of an item that was just added to their cart.

Comment: @CaveJohnson You're right. I thought of that already, too. And I usually prefer verbose wording, as well. (Personal motto: More info is better than less.) But since the tag becomes almost twice as broad then... It'd be almost like a (small) banner. :)

Comment: @wizzwizz4 Good point!

Answer (score 12):

Microsoft uses an icon to show when something is new (rays that show "shiny"). Here's an example taken from their website:
[image: Microsoft OneDrive with a new file called FY Budget Projection]

I'm not sure that there's a universally understood pattern for this, so testing with your particular audience might be good.

Comment: Would you interpret this as _new_ if you wouldn't know it, especially at first sight? I wouldn't.

Comment: Hence my recommendation to test.

Comment: I'd say it's a learned icon, for sure, but not impossible to deduce from context. Certainly in the context of an online storage service like OneDrive, a common workflow is to upload a file and see the file appear in the list, bearing this icon. After a couple times, I'd bet that many users will be able to guess that it's a "new item" indicator.

Comment: When I first saw this icon it looked like a broken loading spinner. A blue dot is more indicative of "unread" or "new".

Comment: @Tvde1 : the problem of blue dots is that there are a big % of the population with varying degree of color blindness : to them it could be simply a dot, which may or may not seems to indicate newness. Best to always mix color with some other indication (letters, specific shape). maybe a blue "+" could work (or blue dot but with a (white?) "+" inscribed into the dot?)

Comment: @Tvde1 Re Olivier's comment: "[**Both** \[icon and color\] **is best.**](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/visual-indicators-differentiators/)".

Comment: Another consideration with blue dots is that they indicate that the user hasn't interacted with it yet - read the email, etc. A 30-day-old unread email might still have a blue dot.

Comment: I don't think this is "new", but rather "modified"/"syncing".

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse I edited a file in my OneDrive to test, and the icon didn't reappear after modification. It looks like it's just for new files.

Answer (score 12):

Notification feeds (e.g. Gmail, Reddit, etc.) often use a different background color to indicate unread. That also gives you the option to adjust the color based on factors such as why or when it was added.

Comment: Example on your screen right now: the Stack Exchange inbox.

Comment: @Barmar: Which still confuses me every now and then, as I sometimes think "color = unread; white = normal".

Comment: @user1686 What exactly do you mean by that? If there are unread answers/comments in your inbox there's a white-on-red overlay to the inbox icon with the number of new, isnt' it? Or are there different skins available for SE sites? ... afa ... I just checked my profile but I didn't find any skin setting(s).

Comment: @GeroldBroser: It's not always the topmost ones that are still "new" (unread), as it's deliberate that they're not all automatically marked as seen. As a result, sometimes it has white (unread) items at the middle or bottom and gray (read) ones at the top. For comparison, the _other_ inbox right next to it – the received points popup – has the complete **opposite** color scheme, with new items having a colorful background while the rest of the popup is white, so it has white (read) items at the bottom and blue (unread) ones at the top...

Comment: @GeroldBroser I think the network inbox is the same across all SE sites. I think his point is just that he gets the color association backwards, he expects the white background to be on the "normal" read messages. I remember it just because the white background is easier to read, so it needs to be read.

Comment: @Barmar & user1686: Ah, it's about the inbox drop-down's backgrounds. I thought it was about the inbox icon's colors. Thx for clarifying! Yes, red for read, white for unread is counter-intuitive. Red is the strongest warning color – AFAIR/K stemming from blood: If you see it (outside slaughterhouses, medical care or the like) something went (more or less terribly) wrong. Immediate action is required.

Comment: @GeroldBroser The inbox icon doesn't change color for me, it just gets a badge with a count of the number of unread messages.

Comment: @Barmar Yes, same here. I mentioned that in [a prev comment](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/145818/are-there-conventions-to-indicate-a-new-item-in-a-list/145825#comment226887_145825) (to user1686), too.

Comment: @GeroldBroser: I wasn't saying it's *red* in color, necessarily (the "read" items actually have a gray background), but the point remains that it's the opposite of what I've grown to expect. I suppose an important part of the design is that the "points" popup has enough padding on the sides around a colored row, making it clear that white is the default background of that popup, while in the "notifications" popup both colors extend equally all the way to the edge and it's no longer clear which is the main color.

Comment: @user1686 Everything's fine if you'd said that. The read items have a...wait...on one, my main display it looks like light red background, on the other it's gray in fact. Sh...oot, is my main monitor going to die? ... Phew, no, it was Win 10's night light setting turned on. But now, when turned off there's no background color to see in the inbox drop-down at all, not at any msg, be it read or unread.

Answer (score 7):

In Apple's Mail app, unread, therefore new messages are denoted with a blue circle next to the email subject line.

[image]

Comment: > unread, therefore new
I'd say that's a pretty big leap. An item may remain unread for years, and you can't conclude that is new. I think the other direction makes more sense (new, therefore unread) and even that will not be true as soon as you open and read it

Answer (score 3):

Mail applications (for example, the Apple Mail application) sometimes used a colored dot to indicate a new (or unread) message.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I've seen a many-pointed star used for this, e.g.:  (perhaps not rendered correctly due to your browser missing according font - click on the link to view it). A similar symbol is commonly used on retail packaging to attract attention to new features.

Unicode also offers[These](http://www.amp-what.com/unicode/search/three%20rays)emphasis rays. Similar symbols are often used to highlight changes in comic strips and visual novels.

Or even a simple (or fancier) [exclamation mark](http://www.amp-what.com/unicode/search/exclamation).

Comment: The "many-pointed star" (Officially: _heavy twelve pointed black star_) isn't rendered correctly (in FF 102.8.0 [01F7D3 in square] and Chrome 110.0.5481.100 [empty upright rectangle]) here. It can be seen at http://www.amp-what.com/unicode/search/%F0%9F%9F%93 though.

Comment: works fine here in both.  maybe you need more fonts.

Comment: Then most probably yes. It's a (castrated) company laptop... \*sigh*. And then this could be a no-go since many users work in a company with machines installed/controlled/restricted centrally.

Comment: you can still use the symbols, using graphics instead of fonts, or use a webfont etc

Comment: Re: "need more fonts", SE is forcing [system fonts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/364048/we-are-switching-to-system-fonts-on-may-10-2021), so depending on the OS, it might not display well.

Comment: To avoid display issues with Unicode symbols, the best solution is probably to just post an image (which could also serve to show the symbol as it's actually used in practice, in context with surrounding UI elements, which is often useful).